# Python Requests - Status 403

Tags: python, web-scraping, request

I'm trying to scrape a website.
For this I found the API call in the network tab and I converted this from cURL to Python code.

The code I'm using is this :

```
import requests

cookies = {
    'bw_BrowserId': '06160135625704565853766325744800269604',
    '_gcl_au': '1.1.1661658686.1660753544',
    '_ga': 'GA1.2.1596995754.1660753545',
    'BETWAY_ENSIGHTEN_PRIVACY_Marketing': '1',
    'BETWAY_ENSIGHTEN_PRIVACY_Analytics': '1',
    'bwui_cookieToastDismissed': 'true',
    'ssc_DeviceId': '0bccd9bb-9f38-4ceb-b225-2956e2163d27',
    'ssc_DeviceId_HttpOnly': '0bccd9bb-9f38-4ceb-b225-2956e2163d27',
    'ai_user': 'v0JA/|2022-08-17T16:25:54.617Z',
    'ens_firstVisit': '1660753692684',
    'TrackingVisitId': '9fafd376-a39b-4b57-b886-025e9118abd4',
    'hash': '9fafd376-a39b-4b57-b886-025e9118abd4',
    'bw_SessionId': '26269b02-4f10-40ab-881f-0ab910e0624d',
    'AMCVS_74756B615BE2FD4A0A495EB8%40AdobeOrg': '1',
    'AMCV_74756B615BE2FD4A0A495EB8%40AdobeOrg': '359503849%7CMCIDTS%7C19224%7CMCMID%7C25582052571887037000237579884308421467%7CMCAAMLH-1661505659%7C6%7CMCAAMB-1661505659%7CRKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y%7CMCCIDH%7C325484274%7CMCOPTOUT-1660908059s%7CNONE%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C5.0.1',
    '_gid': 'GA1.2.609645725.1660900859',
    's_cc': 'true',
    '_sp_srt_ses.c606': '*',
    'StaticResourcesVersion': '12.63.0.6',
    'Referrer': 'https%3A%2F%2Fbetway.be%2F',
    'ssc_btag': '9fafd376-a39b-4b57-b886-025e9118abd4',
    'userLanguage': 'en',
    'SpinSportVisitId': '7bc64bde-b36b-4975-b9a6-409c2022b583',
    'ssc_btag': '9fafd376-a39b-4b57-b886-025e9118abd4',
    'domainCookie': 'betway.be',
    'TimezoneOffset': '120',
    'ens_firstPageView': 'false',
    's_sq': '%5B%5BB%5D%5D',
    'gpv_pn': 'en%3Asports%3Agrp%3Asoccer%3Abelgium%3Afirst-division-a',
    'ai_session': 'udmXK|1660900861941|1660901877478.7',
    '_sp_srt_id.c606': '543c5eed-4191-4fe4-9a12-2290ac66f159.1660753575.2.1660901885.1660753693.d11643b1-24de-4e19-9d73-ac53449c3394',
    '__cf_bm': 'Sa7Rp4hc9Nq05HINmC..na9lSbrKbBUL.y2IEcIwSvg-1660902067-0-AV5J+4G7y/17ma4+56V8WTPLipEo7yKH8tK5NNyQMds04M9Mzbu9m2k0/8yVtalvPB85r/tTMJCif9NKjBI+6WI=',
}

headers = {
    'authority': 'sports.betway.be',
    'accept': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    # Requests sorts cookies= alphabetically
    # 'cookie': 'bw_BrowserId=06160135625704565853766325744800269604; _gcl_au=1.1.1661658686.1660753544; _ga=GA1.2.1596995754.1660753545; BETWAY_ENSIGHTEN_PRIVACY_Marketing=1; BETWAY_ENSIGHTEN_PRIVACY_Analytics=1; bwui_cookieToastDismissed=true; ssc_DeviceId=0bccd9bb-9f38-4ceb-b225-2956e2163d27; ssc_DeviceId_HttpOnly=0bccd9bb-9f38-4ceb-b225-2956e2163d27; ai_user=v0JA/|2022-08-17T16:25:54.617Z; ens_firstVisit=1660753692684; TrackingVisitId=9fafd376-a39b-4b57-b886-025e9118abd4; hash=9fafd376-a39b-4b57-b886-025e9118abd4; bw_SessionId=26269b02-4f10-40ab-881f-0ab910e0624d; AMCVS_74756B615BE2FD4A0A495EB8%40AdobeOrg=1; AMCV_74756B615BE2FD4A0A495EB8%40AdobeOrg=359503849%7CMCIDTS%7C19224%7CMCMID%7C25582052571887037000237579884308421467%7CMCAAMLH-1661505659%7C6%7CMCAAMB-1661505659%7CRKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y%7CMCCIDH%7C325484274%7CMCOPTOUT-1660908059s%7CNONE%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C5.0.1; _gid=GA1.2.609645725.1660900859; s_cc=true; _sp_srt_ses.c606=*; StaticResourcesVersion=12.63.0.6; Referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fbetway.be%2F; ssc_btag=9fafd376-a39b-4b57-b886-025e9118abd4; userLanguage=en; SpinSportVisitId=7bc64bde-b36b-4975-b9a6-409c2022b583; ssc_btag=9fafd376-a39b-4b57-b886-025e9118abd4; domainCookie=betway.be; TimezoneOffset=120; ens_firstPageView=false; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; gpv_pn=en%3Asports%3Agrp%3Asoccer%3Abelgium%3Afirst-division-a; ai_session=udmXK|1660900861941|1660901877478.7; _sp_srt_id.c606=543c5eed-4191-4fe4-9a12-2290ac66f159.1660753575.2.1660901885.1660753693.d11643b1-24de-4e19-9d73-ac53449c3394; __cf_bm=Sa7Rp4hc9Nq05HINmC..na9lSbrKbBUL.y2IEcIwSvg-1660902067-0-AV5J+4G7y/17ma4+56V8WTPLipEo7yKH8tK5NNyQMds04M9Mzbu9m2k0/8yVtalvPB85r/tTMJCif9NKjBI+6WI=',
    'origin': 'https://sports.betway.be',
    'referer': 'https://sports.betway.be/en/sports/grp/soccer/belgium/first-division-a',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="104", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="104"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

json_data = {
    'LanguageId': 1,
    'ClientTypeId': 2,
    'BrandId': 3,
    'JurisdictionId': 3,
    'ClientIntegratorId': 1,
    'ExternalIds': [
        10053087,
        10057931,
        10056949,
        10057933,
        10057940,
        10057941,
        10057939,
    ],
    'MarketCName': 'win-draw-win',
    'ScoreboardRequest': {
        'ScoreboardType': 3,
        'IncidentRequest': {},
    },
    'BrowserId': 3,
    'OsId': 3,
    'ApplicationVersion': '',
    'BrowserVersion': '104.0.0.0',
    'OsVersion': 'NT 10.0',
    'SessionId': None,
    'TerritoryId': 21,
    'CorrelationId': '068b74ad-f718-47ab-beab-47991421a4b8',
    'VisitId': '7bc64bde-b36b-4975-b9a6-409c2022b583',
    'ViewName': 'sports',
    'JourneyId': '97162fd9-0a34-4057-9e36-12a150a40bde',
}

response = requests.post('https://sports.betway.be/api/Events/v2/GetEvents', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, json=json_data)
```

If I look in my browser, this is giving me the correct data I want, but unfortunately in Python I'm getting status 403.
Can someone help me out please?
Thx!

Comment: 403 means you are unauthorized, do you need to be logged in ?
Can you show the actual response ?

Comment: What's the original url of the page being hydrated from that api endpoint?

Comment: hello, original link is https://sports.betway.be/en/sports/grp/soccer/belgium/first-division-a